# .NET encoding issue of mail attachment (.csv)

Tags: c#, encoding

I use following code to send a attachment (.csv) with **Chinese** characters. However, MS excel fails to disply the characters properly, it displays something like "¨å¯¹æ–°ç". Is it because I didn't set some property when sending the mail?

Thanks for any advise.

```
                byte[] attachBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(attachText);
                ms.Write(attachBytes, 0, attachBytes.Length);
                // Set the position to the beginning of the stream.
                ms.Position = 0;
                ContentType ct = new ContentType(MediaTypeNames.Text.Plain);

                Attachment attactment = new Attachment(ms, attachFileName);
                message.Attachments.Add(attactment);
```

Answer (score 2):

i think you need an extra encoding setup for the mail body object, something like this:

```
message.BodyEncoding = UTF8
```

Comment: Excell is also often poor in detecting content encoding at the next stage (save to temp location - losing some metadata - and open). Indeed, it's gotten worse than it used to be. You could try putting a BOM at the beginning of the file as a hint that it is UTF-8 content.

Answer (score 2):

Setting the attachments encoding to `Encoding.UTF32` could help. Assuming `attachText` is a `string` and you only want to add a .csv you could shorten your code by using the [`Attachment.CreateAttachmentFromString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.attachment.createattachmentfromstring%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) method:

```
var attachment = Attachment.CreateAttachmentFromString(attachText,
                                                       "filename.csv",
                                                       Encoding.UTF32,
                                                       "text/csv");
message.Attachments.Add(attachment);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found some solution:

```
        byte[] bom = new byte[] { (byte)0xEF, (byte)0xBB, (byte)0xBF };
        var csvStr = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bom) + csv.ToString();
```

Works fine for me